# BATCH "set" command issue

Tags: batch-file

I want a code that can see if a 'set's exist or not.

Example:

```
@echo of
// Now the thing i want:
if not exist "%user%" (
goto :Register
)
:login
call Functions\user.bat
echo Hello %user%!
pause

:register
echo Register..
pause
```

Now how do i get my batch file to check if %user% exist or not. %user% is not a folder in my script btw.

Comment: The question is unclear to me. There isn't any set command in your batch. If you want to know if a var is set use `if defined varname` See [ss64.com/nt/Set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and  [ss64.com/nt/if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if not exist "%user%"
```

Tests whether a file or directory exists with the name *contents of the variable `user`*

```
if not defined user
```

Tests whether the variable `user` has been set in the environment.